# What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\xi (t), \eta (t))$ at $t=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was given the following problem in an assignment:

Consider the function $$f(t,x,y)=3\cos(x-t)+2xy+(8+4t)\cos(y)$$

and note that $(x,y)\mapsto f(0,x,y)$ has a local maximum at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.
As $t$ varies, the function $(x,y)\mapsto f(t,x,y)$ at the nearby point $(x,y)=(\xi(t),\eta(t))$ in such a way that $(\xi(0),\eta(0))=(0,0)$ and $t\mapsto (\xi(t),\eta(t))$ is a differentiable function of t.

What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\xi(t),\eta(t))$ when $t=0$?

It turns out that the answer is $1$ but I do not understand why. Would someone be able to walk me through the steps of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I get $4$. Since you expressed the thing as a function of a single variable t, it's also unclear whether you mean the partial derivative with respect to the first argument or the total derivative wrt t. Either way, I seem to get 4. Are you sure there's no typo?

Comment: well i got 4 when i did it as well but when i entered that as the answer, the program said i was wrong. I then went on to type in 1 and it worked. I don't at all understand why that is the case.. I'm hoping its just an error on the part of my professor. I copied the wording of the question verbatim.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you there. Either we're both making a similar mistake or they forgot about the $4$ in front of the $t.$